# Table at bottom of two-column environment stretching two tables

Tags: tables, enumerate, minipage, tabu

I have been assigned the task of producing a table as the one shown in the picture. I have problems with placement of the rules, the background color and the caption-font and caption counter(Table I) being too large. A quick response would be appreciated.[image]

Comment: I wouldn't call that a table -- it looks like a messy pile up of text and numerical values

Comment: what you try so far? help us to help you. wrote code from scratch is not a fun ...

Comment: You need to tell us which document class you use.

Comment: Are you allowed to place the table at the top of the page, or does it have to be at the bottom? Please advise.

Comment: The document class that I am using is llncs.
The table does have to be at the bottom. I need that grey background too. I need as close to a photocopy of this as possible.

I have managed to get it to the bottom and centred it. What I need help with is the font size and spacing of the caption, the background-color and the rules (\hrule does not have this exact effect).

Answer (score 1):

in lack of information and not knowing what you try so far, which document class you use, does gray table's background must be ...

[image]

instead of table environment i would rather use `enumerate` environment. for placing on the same page where table is inserted serve `{stfloats}˙:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{stfloats} % for positioning of table* on the same page

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{table*}[b]
\caption{table caption}
\rule{\linewidth}{1pt}
\begin{enumerate}[nosep, leftmargin=*, label=(\alph*)]  
\item   \lipsum[11]
\item   \lipsum[11]
\item   \lipsum[11]
\end{enumerate}
\rule{\linewidth}{1pt}
\end{table*}
\lipsum[2-5]
\end{document}
```

Comment: any news? or you already forgot on your question?